# How to replace string without checking the inline html tags in php

Tags: php, regex

This is the text which is getting from html dom:

```
"Established in <b>2004</b>, <strong>AssistanZ</strong> has become one of the most"
```

I need to replace the above string as `"Established in 2004, AssistanZ has become one of the most"`.

String compare is not working because of the html elements. I cannot replace the html because it will come dynamically.

Could you please tell anyone how to fix this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$oldValue = $value->skey;
$newValue = $value->svalue;
str_replace($oldValue,$newValue,$text);
```

Comment: So you basically just want to remove the HTML from the string? If yes, then you could use PHP's built in [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function instead of trying to reinvent it using regex.

Comment: What about splitting the text and replacing word by word?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of html tags, use strip_tags function

```
strip_tags("Established in <b>2004</b>, <strong>AssistanZ</strong> has become one of the most")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in action:

```
$text = "Established in 2004, AssistanZ has become one of the most amazing things on the planet.";
$oldvalue = strip_tags("Established in <b>2004</b>, <strong>AssistanZ</strong> has become one of the most");
$newValue = "I am one of the";

echo str_replace($oldvalue, $newValue, $text);
```